# How do I query Jira to search for all issues in a project for which no user has logged work in last week?

Tags: jira, jql

I need a way to get all the issues (which are not resolved or closed) of a particular project for which no user has logged work in last week.

For example, let's say I have a project = 'abc' with five issues 'i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4' and 'i5' and there are two users 'u1' and 'u2' who can log work in these issues.

Last week -  'u1' logged work in issues 'i2' and 'u2' logged work in issues 'i2' and 'i3'.

So the desired result is - 'i1' and 'i4'.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
project = ABC and status not in (Resolved, Closed) and worklogDate > startOfDay(-7)
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by installing the [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin and using JQL to [query for workLogged information](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-Worklogs):

```
project=ABC and status not in (Resolved, Closed) and issuefunction not in worklogged("after -7d")
```

If you need to do fancier queries based on the attributes of the users and so forth, see the [commented() documentation](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-commented%28commentquery%29) for reference.

Comment: > Field 'issuefunction' does not exist or you do not have permission to view it.

Is that associated with the Script Runner plugin?

Comment: @oligofren, yes, it is.